# When capturing a parameter pack in a lambda some ints lose their value

Tags: c++, lambda, variadic-templates

So I have a variadic template class that has a method in which arguments for the template are captured in a lambda. Later that lambda is called. Problem is, ints that are either at the front or the back of the pack lose their value.

Here is a simplified example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void doPrint() {}

template <typename Arg, typename... Args>
void doPrint(Arg arg, Args... args) {
    std::cout << arg << std::endl;
    doPrint(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <typename... Args>
void print(Args... args) {
    doPrint(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

class IntWrapper {
public:
    IntWrapper(int val) : val(val) {}

    int val;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const IntWrapper& value) {
    out << value.val;
    return out;
}


template <typename... Args>
class TestClass {
public:
    void createWrapper(Args... args) {
        wrapper = [&]() -> void {
            print(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        };
    }

    std::function<void()> wrapper;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string string = "abc";

    std::cout << "Test 1:" << std::endl;

    TestClass<int, const IntWrapper&, int> test1;
    test1.createWrapper(1, IntWrapper(2), 3);
    test1.wrapper();

    std::cout << std::endl << "Test 2:" << std::endl;

    TestClass<int, const IntWrapper&> test2;
    test2.createWrapper(1, IntWrapper(2));
    test2.wrapper();

    std::cout << std::endl << "Test 3:" << std::endl;

    TestClass<const IntWrapper&, int> test3;
    test3.createWrapper(IntWrapper(1), 2);
    test3.wrapper();

    std::cout << std::endl << "Test 4:" << std::endl;

    TestClass<const IntWrapper&, int, const IntWrapper&> test4;
    test4.createWrapper(IntWrapper(1), 2, IntWrapper(3));
    test4.wrapper();
}
```

This is the output I get:

```
Test 1:
1
2
3

Test 2:
32764
2

Test 3:
1
32764

Test 4:
1
0
3
```

As you can see, the wrapped ints always keep their values, but the ints sometimes don't.
I know it works if I capture by copy and don't use forward, but I can't do that in my actual use case.

So, why doesn't this work? And is there any way to fix it?

**EDIT:** Okay, well, so obviously I was being stupid by letting the variables go out of scope in the example. It works with local variables. However, the problem still occurs in my use case, where the variables aren't out of scope. I'll try to transfer the problem to my example and try again.

Comment: I suspect UB somewhere, since I get different [result](http://ideone.com/qEg1g1).

Comment: `TestClass<Args...>::createWrapper()` is capturing references to local variables.

Comment: as an expansion aschepler's comment, you will want to capture by value the arguments, ... wrapper = [=]() -> void ....

Comment: @aschepler The answer section is below ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So what's happening is that your references are going out of scope before you use them.

```
test1.createWrapper(1, IntWrapper(2), 3);
```

all of those variables you passed go out of scope by the time you get to

```
test1.wrapper();
```

if you stored them locally then called, something like

`int x = 1, z = 3;
 IntWrapper y(2);
 test1.createWrapper(x, y, z); 
 test1.wrapper();`

it should work. For your actual code you need to either make sure that
the values are still valid from when you call createWrapper to whenever you call wrapper, or you'll need to capture by value in createWrapper.

Edit:

I missed this:

```
TestClass<int, const IntWrapper&, int> test1;
```

for test1 you aren't forwarding the int's passed in (x and z in my example above) you're forwarding the copy of x and z because those int's are being passed by value. If you change to

```
TestClass<int&, const IntWrapper&, int&> test1;
```

then I think it would work.

Comment: *pass by value*: you meant to say *capture by value*.

Comment: Good catch. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You'll cruise through the reputation league table with excellent answers like this.

Comment: That's correct. As mentioned in my edit, I didn't really think when I wrote the example. However, it happens in the actual code I'm having problems with even though there the variables aren't going out of scope. I'll mark this as the right answer in case anyone actually has the problem I created in my example.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, createWrapper will expand to createWrapper(int, IntWrapper, int) (for test1's call to it). Ie when you do a forward, you're doing it on the copy of the args created by createWrapper. Then when createWrapper finishes, those args are gone. So createWrapper should take args by ref or const ref then no?

Comment: It will be createWrapper(int, IntWrapper const&, int) actually, my bad. But that would explain why the IntWrapper's work, but the int's do not.